# Long if statements and PSR-2

Tags: php, coding-style

I'm about to migrate some code to the PSR-2 standard. In my code i have if statements with multiple lines as expression:

```
if (    $field->getBlockMode() == FieldInterface::BLOCK_MODE_HIDEVAR &&
        !isset($this->enabledBlocks[$field->getBlock()])
) {

}
```

What's the best practice to write such expressions?

Comment: Like however you want. The recommendation is to make the test-statement shorter: It will be unreadable regardless _how_ you write it.

Comment: The Problem is, that after the "if (" whitespace isn't allowed so i can't set the expression to the same hoirizobntal position as the following one. And as i understand it, i can't insert a line breake after the "if (" ether.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about making it a one-liner to avoid that problem and make the statement more readable:

```
$blockModeIsHidevar = $field->getBlockMode() == FieldInterface::BLOCK_MODE_HIDEVAR;
$blockNotEnabled = !isset($this->enabledBlocks[$field->getBlock()]);

if ($blockModeIsHidevar && $blockNotEnabled) {

}
```

**Alternative:**

I usually do it with methods, this *could* looke like that:

```
if ($this->blockModeIsHidevar($field) && $this->blockNotEnabled($field)) {

}
// ...
private function blockModeIsHidevar($field)
{
    return $field->getBlockMode() == FieldInterface::BLOCK_MODE_HIDEVAR
}
private function blockNotEnabled($field)
{
    return !isset($this->enabledBlocks[$field->getBlock()])
}
```

This way, the optimization of `&&` still takes place.

Comment: If it is necessary for you that the second condition does not get evaluated if the first is false, you could extract the checks to methods/functions instead of variables.

Comment: @Johni - No, this kind of change won't affect performance in any measurable way. In any case, good coding style should generally trump performance.

Comment: Ok, so i think i will go with the functions.

Answer (score 4):

Extract it into shorter boolean expressions first, then use those variables in your `if()` statement.

ie:

```
$hideVarMode = $field->getBlockMode() === FieldInterface::BLOCK_MODE_HIDEVAR;
$enabledBlock = !isset($this->enabledBlocks[$field->getBlock()];
if($hideVarMode && $enabledBlock) {
    ....
}
```

(note, I also turned your first test into a triple-equal, since this is likely to be better; feel free to change it back if that doesn't work for you)